# Why is my bash shell script working on v 3.2.5 and failing on 4.1.2?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

My bash shell script is working on Bash 3.2.5.
I have an input file that contains the following content:

```
1234567
2345678
3456789
4567890
```

and a bash shell script that has the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
content=($(cat data.txt | awk {'print $1'}))
for (( i=0 ; i<${#content[@]} ; i++ ))
do
  if (( i==0 ))
  then
    ele=`echo ${content[$i]}`
  else
    ele=`echo ","${content[$i]}`
  fi
  all=`echo $all$ele`
done
# should be a string of csv: works on bash 3.2.5 - fails on bash 4.1.2
echo $all
```

When run with Bash 3.2.5 it outputs: (expected output; correct)

```
1234567,2345678,3456789,4567890
```

But when run with Bash 4.1.2 it outputs: (the last number in the file; not correct)

```
,4567890
```

Why is the same code failing in Bash 4.1.2?

Comment: When you added debugging output and tried out the various parts of the script to see which part was going wrong, what did you find? Which line is behaving differently on 4.1.2?

Comment: The assignments like ``ele=`echo ","${content[$i]}"` `` and ``all=`echo $all$ele` `` should not be using back-ticks or `$(…)` command substitution; you should be writing simply `all="$all$sep${content[$i]}"` where you can have `sep=""` before the loop and `sep=","` after the assignment to `all`.  And there's still probably room for improvement, though I'm not sure I'd necessarily bother.

Comment: Also, FWIW, I tried the script with Bash versions 3.2.57(1)-release and 4.3.27(2)-release on Mac OS X 10.10.2, and I get the same correct (expected) output with both.  You might have run into a bug in Bash 4.1.2, though it's pretty unlikely; this is basic functionality.  Have you reviewed what happens with `bash -x yourscript.sh`?  Have you checked your data file for Windows-style CRLF line endings?  When my `data.txt` file has Windows-style line endings, I get the 'Bash 4.1.2' output.  Did you somehow copy the material to the machine running Bash 4.1.2 via a Windows system?

Comment: Or, in other words, are you sure you're running with the same data file on both machines where you are testing it?

Comment: To extend Jonathan's comment, on the machine with bash 4, does the data file have `\r\n` line endings?

Comment: Thanks all for helping out here; ruakh - the assigment to all statement didn't seem to persist the previously set value. so $all = <blank>

Comment: Jonathan Leffler / glenn jackman - I'm going to check the od of the file... for CRLF..  in both environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this issue is; Due to the crlf in the file that the script running on 4.1.2 is using.

Jonathan Leffler and glenn jackman put me on to the answer to the question.
My file created on the linux machine running bash 4.1.2 was created dos style with crlf. The 3.2.5 file was created with lf as the end of line marker. I didn't think to look at the data file itself and I'm well aware of this causing issues in the past with other scenarios.

I've learned about different and better ways of doing this from all the posts above and I'll be trying them all out.

Thank you again.

Here are more details of the two systems I was working on:

bash 4.2.1:

```
$ uname -a
Linux n0c 2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Aug 2 17:04:38 EDT 2013 x86_64     x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ bash -version
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

bash 3.2.5:

```
[root@ww ~]# uname -a
Linux ww.com 2.6.18-028stab101.1-ent #1 SMP Sun Jun 24 20:22:25 MSD 2012 i686   i686 i386 GNU/Linux
[root@ww ~]# bash -version
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (i386-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `echo` to set the contents of a variable is just plain .. wrong. When I say wrong, I mean, you can do it, but there is absolutely no reason to use `command substitution` of an `echo` statement to fill the variables in this case. Likewise, there is no reason to use `cat` piped to `awk` to fill the array. Filling the array is much easier done with just a simple redirection.

By eliminating all the unneeded `command substitution` of `echo` and `piped` commands, you eliminate a lot of opportunity for error. Here is an update that will work on either 3 or 4.

```
#!/bin/bash
content=( $( <data.txt) )
for (( i=0 ; i<${#content[@]} ; i++ ))
do
    if (( i==0 ))
    then
        ele="${content[i]}"
    else
        ele=",${content[i]}"
    fi
    all="${all}${ele}"
done
echo $all
```

**Output**

```
$ bash bash34fail.sh
1234567,2345678,3456789,4567890
```

Comment: OK, +1. Note that there are still a lot of simplifications and improvements that can be made, such as dispensing with `ele`, using `+=`, moving `${content[0]}` outside the loop, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't helping with understanding the symptoms you're seeing, but your code can be completely rewritten as

```
paste -d , -s data.txt
```

If you want to use bash constructs:

```
mapfile -t numbers < data.txt   # read the lines of the file into an array
(IFS=,; echo "${numbers[*]}")   # join the array with a comma
```

However, check your data file does not contain carriage returns: `oc -d data.txt` and fix it with `dos2unix` or `sed -i 's/\r$//' data.txt`

Answer (score 0):

<sup>*Transferring salient comments into an answer.*</sup>

The assignments like:

```
ele=`echo ","${content[$i]}"`
all=`echo $all$ele`
```

should not be using back-ticks `` `…` `` or `$(…)` command substitution; you should be writing simply

```
all="$all$sep${content[$i]}"
```

where you can have `sep=""` before the loop and `sep=","` after the assignment to all.

Also, FWIW, I tried the script with Bash versions 3.2.57(1)-release and 4.3.27(2)-release on Mac OS X 10.10.2, and I get the same correct (expected) output with both.

- Have you reviewed what happens with `bash -x yourscript.sh`?  This is a basic and very important shell script debugging technique.
- **Have you checked your data file for Windows-style CRLF line endings?**

When my `data.txt` file has Windows-style CRLF (carriage return, line feed) line endings, I get the 'Bash 4.1.2' output. When my `data.txt` file has Unix-style NL (newline, aka line feed) line endings, I get the 'Bash 3.2.5 output.

Did you somehow copy the material to the machine running Bash 4.1.2 via a Windows system?  Or, in other words, are you sure you're running with exactly the same data file on both machines where you are testing it?

I'd simplify the script to:

```
sep=""
all=""
while read number
do
    all="$all$sep$number"
    sep=","
done < data.txt
echo "$all"
```

There are other ways of achieving the same result, but that's pretty straight-forward and doesn't use any subshells, unlike the original script which uses a profusion of them.